# Taylor series and Maclaurin series problems

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm currently working on these two problems, and I'm getting really confused with them. Can someone walk me through them?

> 1. Find the Maclaurin Series for $f(x)=\cos\left(\sqrt x\right)$ and use it to evaluate $\int\cos\left(\sqrt x\right)\mathrm dx$ as a series.
> 2. Find the Taylor Series for $f(x)=\ln(2-x)$ about $x=-1$.

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/0zqQ4IK

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial to type your question with Latex.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$1)$ $$\cos (x ^{1/2}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n/2}}{(2n)!} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{n}}{(2n)!}$$

If $[a,b] \subset (-1,1)$ then you may use termwise integration.

$2)$ $$\ln (2 - x) = \ln (3 - 1 - x) = \ln (3  - (x + 1)) = \ln 3 + \ln \Big(1 -\frac{1}{3}(x + 1) \Big)$$

Comment: Was my work for the taylor series question correct up to the point I got to?

Comment: Please, write in Latex, it's way better.

Comment: Do you know the series of $\ln (1 - x)$? And $\cos x$?

Comment: Im not sure how to use latex sorry. I do not know the series of the two.

Comment: I've just linked to a tutorial to use latex. And it would be very helpful if you knew them. It's not difficult to derive them, at all. You may check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706282/how-are-the-taylor-series-derived) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x).

Comment: You're most welcome! One more thing, I believe you should also read this [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).