# Show the correctness of this derivation to the Taylor's Theorem?

Tags: integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

As to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/706301/681195) beautiful derivation of the Taylor's Theorem, wouldn't it break the equality when we add the term $f(0)$ to the right side of $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt$ ?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your concern. Can you rephrase? Where are you adding $f(0)$ somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The reason is as follows: we have
$$ \int_{0}^{x} f'(t) dt = \left [ f(t) \right ] ^ x _ 0 = f(x) - f(0)$$
(not just $f(x)$). Thus:
$$f(x)=f(0)+ \int_{0}^{x} f'(t) dt$$