# How does $e^x\cdot e^X$ equal $e^{x+X}$?

Tags: exponential-function

I know that they equal each other, but when I'm trying to prove it, something doesn't match. Please mind the difference between the two equations, one is a lowercase $x$ and the other is an uppercase $x.$ I know that the formula to get $e^x$ is $\frac{x^n}{n!}$. So I apply on $e^x$and it becomes $1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\cdots$ and the same for $e^X$. [image]This image shows what I'm thinking, and what happens when I multiply them on each other. But I want to go more deeper and show the full equation of the numbers shown, for example, showing $\frac{1}{6}x^3$ and others as well. If I did, there would be a total of 16 numbers shown that are arranged in order of degrees. So I try to prove it like [image] this picture. But the problem shows when I try to prove it more. I tried proving it more, but $\frac{1}{6}(x+X)^3$ won't work. Than what should I do to make it work? Or what formula should I use?

Comment: The title was wrong and I have edited it. I hope you agree with the new title.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you tell me the change? I can't access the change history.

Comment: You had typed $e^{x}+X$ instead of $e^{x+X}$.

Comment: Use $$
\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^n } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {b_n x^n } } \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k b_{n - k} } } \right)x^n } 
$$ and the binomial theorem.

Comment: which term of $\frac{1}{6}(x+X)^3$ you could not find?

Comment: @amitava I'm confused how they add up, as $(x+X)^3$ is x³+3x²y+3xy²+y³

Comment: Yes, and you need to multiply 1/6 to each term, then which term you did not get in the expansion of $e^{x+X}$

Comment: For all who looked at my question, please look at the end as well, I've updated and added another question I'm not sure about

Comment: Using both upper-case and lower-case versions of the same variable in a calculation on a blackboard is pretty diabolical. I reckon proving $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$ is easier than proving $e^xe^X=e^{x+X}$.

Comment: @Heech.p $(1)(\frac{1}{6}X^3) + (x)(\frac{1}{2}X^2) +(\frac{1}{2}x^2)(X) + (\frac{1}{6}X^3)(1) = \frac{1}{6}(x + X)^3$

Comment: The next four terms will but $\frac 16 X^3 + \frac 12 X^2 x + \frac 12  Xx^2 + \frac 16x^3 = \frac 16(x+X)^3$.  It is assumed you will recognize the pattern and take it for granted without needing any proof that the sum is in increasingly larger "chunks".  The $n$th chunk will be $n+1$ terms:  $\frac 1{n!}X^n + \frac 1{(n-1)!}X^{n-1}x + ...... + \frac 1{n!}x^n = \frac 1{n!}(x+X)^n$.  If you need to prove it I'd suggest a proof by induction.

Comment: @fleablood I would give this answer an accept and an upvote but it's a comment...:)

Comment: Using pictures instead of text doesn't give math.stackexchange.com a chance to find related question. Using the variables x and X makes the formulas very confusing.So -1

Comment: @miracle173 I understand the second problem, but the first problem I think is not a problem, it depends if someone wants to use pictures or not

Comment: Do you have to prove it using series expansion? Will you accept an alternative proof?

Comment: @Koro the exact answer, that's still not here, that I wanted, was an answer that would show proof, not using formulas and etc, but taking the exact numbers I showed and using them.

Comment: See also: [Prove $e^{x+y}=e^{x}e^{y}$ by using Exponential Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414061) (and other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/414061)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're confused about the arrangement. We should get $e^xe^x=e^{2x}$, which can be written $$e^{2x} = 1 +(2x) + \tfrac{(2x)^2}{2!} + \tfrac{(2x)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
$$=1 + 2x + \tfrac{4x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{8x^3}{3!} + \cdots$$

So let's multiply series:
$$e^x\cdot e^x = \left(1 + x + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\right)\cdot\left(1 + x + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\right)$$
$$= 1\cdot\left(1 + x + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\right) + x\cdot\left(1 + x + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\right) + \tfrac{x^2}{2!}{\cdot\left(1 + x + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\right)}+\cdots$$
$$= (1) + (1\cdot x + x\cdot 1) + (1\cdot \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + x\cdot x + \tfrac{x^2}{2!}\cdot 1) + \cdots $$
$$= 1 + (2)x + (\tfrac1{2!} + 1 + \tfrac1{2!})x^2 + \cdots$$
$$=1 + 2x + \tfrac4{2!}x^2 + \cdots$$
You collect the products of a fixed degree $n$ as
$$1\cdot \tfrac{x^n}{n!} + x\cdot\tfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \tfrac{x^2}{2!}\cdot\tfrac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} + \cdots + \tfrac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}\cdot \tfrac{x^2}{2!} +\tfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\cdot x + \tfrac{x^{n}}{n!}\cdot 1$$
$$= (\tfrac1{n!} + \tfrac{n}{n!} + \tfrac{n(n-1)}{n!} + \tfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n!} + \cdots)x^n$$
Your job is to show that this is $\tfrac{2^n}{n!}x^n$ (expand $(1+1)^n)$ using the binomial formula).

---

**Retry:**

I think you are doing it right, you just didn't collect all terms correctly.

You are really just using the distributive law, like
$$(a + b + c+\cdots)(\textrm{terms}) = a\cdot(\textrm{terms}) + b\cdot(\textrm{terms}) + c\cdot(\textrm{terms})+\cdots$$
For each of the products on the RHS, you need to look for results of the same degree (we're really looking at the exponential series here, of course).

- Constant terms only occur as $1\cdot 1$, in the first product on the RHS.
- Degree 1 terms occur as $1\cdot x$ or $x\cdot 1$ (in the first and second products on the RHS).
- Degree 2 terms occur as $1\cdot x^2$, $x\cdot x$, or $x^2\cdot 1$ (in the first, second, and third products on the RHS).
- Degree 3 terms occur as $1\cdot x^3$, $x\cdot x^2$, $x^2\cdot x$, or $x^3\cdot 1$  (in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th products on the RHS).

And so on.

Comment: This is probably the clearest, but I'm not sure how you got to the end equation which correct :). But all the answers, including your's doesn't help much, because I asked why it would work, so it would be better if you showed how it worked.

Comment: Added to my answer, hope this helps!

Comment: If you would answer using examples or just showing how it would work using the numbers I gave, I would give an upvote and an accept, but this edit is still a bit confusing to me

Comment: But you can of course do what you want

Answer (score 1):

The expression $x+X$ is meaningless as $x$ and $X$ are quite different things (one is scalar, the other one a matrix), hence it is not
$$
e^{x+X}=1+{x+X}+{(x+X)^2\over 2!}+\cdots 
$$
But the following identity turns out to be true:$$e^{xI+X}=1+{xI+X}+{(xI+X)^2\over 2!}+\cdots$$where $I$ is the identity matrix of the same order of $X$. This is indeed true because of the following implication:$$AB=BA\implies e^{A}e^{B}=e^{A+B}$$

Comment: What? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all...

Comment: Ok. How do you define $x+X$ then?

Comment: I asked why it something worked, and you said something different, just didn't help much as it came to an answer I knew, but wanted to prove

Comment: Oops! My bad. I thought $x$ as scalar and $X$ as a matrix :)

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I'm happy you caught your mistake, but I hope you understood that I wanted proof using the numbers I gave, as for your answer, it proved something I already know, but I wanted to prove

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \left( \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a^j}{j!} \right) \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b^k}{k!} \right) \\[10pt]
= & \Big(\bullet\Big) \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b^k}{k!} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \bullet \cdot \frac{b^k}{k!} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\left( \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a^j}{j!} \right) \frac{b^k}{k!} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left( \frac{a^j}{j!} \cdot \frac{b^k}{k!} \right).
\end{align}
This sum includes all the cases where $j+k=0,$ and all cases where $j+k=1$, and all cases where $j+k=2,$ and so on. What are the cases where $j+k=4,$ for example? They are these:
$$
\frac{a^0b^4}{0!4!} + \frac{a^1 b^3}{1!3!} + \frac{a^2b^2}{2!2!} + \frac{a^3 b^1}{3!1!} + \frac{a^4b^0}{4!0!}
$$
That is the same as
\begin{align}
& \frac 1 {4!} \left( \frac{4!}{0!4!} a^0b^4 + \frac{4!}{1!3!} a^1 b^3 + \frac{4!}{2!2!} a^2b^2 + \frac{4!}{3!1!} a^3 b^1 + \frac{4!}{4!0!} a^4b^0 \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {4!} (a+b)^4.
\end{align}
And similarly for other numbers than $4.$ Thus the sum is
$$
\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac 1 {\ell!} (a+b)^\ell = e^{a+b}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at a couple functions. $Y=e^X$ and $y=e^x$.

Then $\ln Y=X$ and $\ln y = x$. $$X+x=\ln (Y)+\ln (y) = \ln (Yy) \Longrightarrow e^{X+x}=Yy=e^Xe^x$$

Ok, so there is a little informal proof using some properties of the natural log.

$$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{z^n}{n!}$$ (Note: I am not using z as a complex variable, only a stand in for x because it is used so much in the question.)

So, $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}+...$$

$$e^X=1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...+\frac{X^n}{n!}+...$$

$$\begin{align*} e^xe^X &= \bigg(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}+... \bigg)\bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...+\frac{X^n}{n!}...\bigg) \\&= 1\bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...\bigg) + x\bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...\bigg)+ \frac{x^2}{2}\bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...+\frac{X^n}{n!}...\bigg)...\\&= \bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2} + \frac{X^3}{6}...\bigg) + \bigg(x+xX+x\frac{X^2}{2}+x\frac{X^3}{6}...\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2}X + \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{X^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}\frac{X^3}{6}...\bigg)+...\\&= 1+(x+X)+\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2}+xX+\frac{X^2}{2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^2X}{2}+\frac{X^2x}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}\bigg)+...\\ &= 1+(x+X)^1 +\frac{(x+X)^2}{2} + \frac{(x+X)^3}{6} + ...\\&= e^{x+X}\end{align*}$$

Another way: $$\begin{align*} e^{x+X}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}(x+X)^j&= \sum_{j=0, 0\le k\le j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!} {j\choose k}x^{j-k}X^k \\ &= \frac{1}{0!}\bigg[{0\choose 0}(x^{0-0}X^0)\bigg] + \frac{1}{1!}\bigg[{1\choose 0}(x^{1-0}X^0)+{1\choose 1}(x^{1-1}X^1)\bigg] +\frac{1}{2!}\bigg[{2\choose 0}(x^{2-0}X^0)+{2\choose 1}(x^{2-1}X^1) + {2\choose 2}(x^{2-2}X^2)\bigg] +...\\&= 1+x+X + \frac{x^2}{2} +xX + \frac{X^2}{2} +\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^2X}{2}+\frac{X^2x}{2}+\frac{X^3}{6}+...\\&= \bigg(1+X + \frac{X^2}{2} + \frac{X^3}{6} + ...\bigg)+\bigg(x +xX + x\frac{X^2}{2}+...\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2 X}{2} +\frac{x^2X^2}{2\cdot 2}+...\bigg)+...\\&= \bigg(1+X + \frac{X^2}{2} + \frac{X^3}{6} + ...\bigg)+x\bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+...\bigg)+\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg(1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+...\bigg)+...\end{align*}$$

You can finish it from there.

The exact reason this works is hidden in the way the Taylor series defines a function. I will direct you to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/706301/803927), which in my opinion, is a really nice and different way of understanding the intuition behind the Taylor series. The [top answer on that page](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/706297/803927) directs to another link of [the proof of the Taylor series as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472960/803927).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following without resorting to series expansion of $e^x$:
We'll use the following famous limit :
$ e^x= \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+n^{-1})^{nx} $ 
Hence, $e^x\cdot e^X=\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+n^{-1})^{nx}\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+n^{-1})^{nX}=\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+n^{-1})^{n(x+X)}=e^{x+X} $